# How to find out which transformation is taking a long time in Spark UI?

Tags: apache-spark

You may have spark code that `join`s, `filter`s, then `groubBy`s something, and at the end does `take(1)`, for example. But when you look at SparkUI, it only shows that `take(1)` is taking a long time as an action that contains all those transformations. And it seems like there's no way to see which transformation is taking a long time.

So, how do I find out which transformation is taking a long time in Spark UI?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stages Tab in spark UI. *Stages tab* displays a summary page that shows the current state of all stages of all jobs in the Spark application.

At the beginning of the page is the summary with the count of all stages by status (active, pending, completed, skipped, and failed)

You need to identify your transformation operation there. If you are using same transformation multiple time you can differentiate by clicking on *details* you can know exact line number from code from where it getting called.

Check the time spend and still if you are not satisfied you can visit *Storage Tab* to check if you persisting your datasets correctly or not. Sometimes id not persisted, spark calculates same things many times.

[image]

Good Luck!